# Помогите вчленить остутствие по складам из базы данных магазинов

Tags: mysql, sql

Подскажите, как можно это реализовать?

Есть база данных с тремя сущностями:

1. магазины(id (pk), nameW) - имя магазина
2. товары в магазинах (id(pk), idgood(FK), IdW(FK), quiantity) - id Товара, id магазина, количество
3. товары (id (pk), nameG) - имя товара

магазины --
магазин1
магазин2
магазин3

Товары_в_магазине ---
товар 1 количество 10 магазин1
товар 1 количество 5 магазин2
товар 1 количество 7 магазин3
товар 2 количество 9 магазин1
товар 2 количество 3 магазин2
товар 3 количество 4 магазин3

Товары ---
товар1
товар2
товар3
товар4
товар5
товар6

нужно найти товары, которые отсутствуют во всех магазинах
т.е. товар4 товар5 и товар6
если товар присутствует хоть в одном магазине, то не учитывается в финальной выборке.

я пока left join добился совокупную выборку получить, с None, но как ее со всеми магазинами одновременно сличить не понимаю.
select * from Товары
left join Магазины
left join Товары_в_магазине on магазины.nameW = Товары_в_магазине.IdW and Товары.nameG = Товары_в_магазине.idgood;

Comment: WHERE NOT EXISTS

Comment: спасибо за ответ. попробую.